# Importing Spatialite database to Postgres on OSX: driver not found?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatialite

I'm trying to import a table called `applications` from a Spatialite database (called mytable.db) to Postgres (v9.6.5) on OSX.

I have Googled and tried the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=planning" spatialitedb applications
```

But I get a "driver not available" error:

```
FAILURE: Unable to open datasource `spatialitedb' with the following drivers.
```

I've installed gdal with the `--complete` option:

```
brew install --env=std --complete --with-postgres gdal
```

How can I import Spatialite to Postgres?

I'm a bit confused by the above command because I don't know how it indicates that it should used `mytable.db` as the source of the data. So it's possible that it isn't actually a driver error at all!

Comment: The syntax is certainly wrong. If you want to convert the whole Spatialite db into PostGIS you must use `mytable.db` as input. If you are interested in one table inside Spatialite db the syntax is "database_name table_name" so in your case `mytable.db applications`,